# Git - Rebasing command when remote branch has been updated

Tags: git, rebase

I am trying to understand what's the correct method to `rebase` my changes in Git

1) I have a `master` branch

2) From master, I've created a `featureX` branch - created from JIRA.

3) I checked out that branch using `git checkout featureX`. It says that it's set up to track the remote branch `featureX` - which is correct. Any push I do on this branch will be tracked @ my remote branch.

```
   x1-----x2------x3-----x4   master
   |
   |
   |
   y1-----y2------y3          featureX
```

4) My feature branch has y1, y2, and y3 commits (not pushed to remote yet). But since I checked out `featureX`, my `master` branch has had othe commits pushed/merged into it from whoever else is working. So I want to rebase my changes by pulling all latest stuff from `master` into my `featureX` branch.

This is where I need to get the clarification.

1) if I do `git checkout featureX` followed by `git rebase master`, does that automatically pull the *latest* changes from `master`? I think it only pulls the changes which are on my local `master` branch i.e. the remote `master` updates won't be there (unless i've updated my local `master`)

```
git checkout featureX
git rebase master   # which master? my local `master` or remote `master`?
```

2) If my assumption is correct, should I always do the following?

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git checkout featureX
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase master` is for local `master`.

if you want to rebase to remote master, use `origin/master` where origin is remote name, and `origin/master` is your local snapshot from remote, you should check that it is synced with remote before you do rebase by using `git pull/fetch`, no need to check out to `master` and then check back to `featureX` though.

So your assumption is correct.

Actually you can rebase to any ref rather than branch name, like commit id or tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes total sense. So I should always use `git rebase <origin/remote/branch/name> to pull remote changes from remote all the time?

Comment: @ha9u63ar My pleasure. Not exactly IMO, just pull remote beforeyou want to merge back to remote or your feature has serious confilct with remote.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout featureX
git rebase master   # which master? my local `master` or remote `master`?
```

--> bring x2, x3, x4 of branch **master** to y1 of branch **featureX**

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git checkout featureX
git rebase master
```

--> You shouldn't do like this. `git pull --rebase`. you try to bring changed points from A to B, then try to bring changed points from B to A. It doesn't like good practices.